# How to implement or introduce socket.io-client from vue test utils?

Tags: vue.js, socket.io, vue-test-utils

When I trigger a function that requests API from $socket.client.emit I received `client` undefined after running `npm run test:unit`. I used 2 package from Vue when using socket-io here's my code from Vue main.js

```
import socket from 'vue-socket.io-extended'
import socketio from 'socket.io-client'

Vue.use(socket, socketio("http://ip_address:port), { store })
```

and here's my code from vue test utils

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

import SocketIOExt from 'vue-socket.io-extended'
import SocketIO from 'socket.io-client'


import { createLocalVue, mount } from '@vue/test-utils'

import Login from '@/components/authentication/Login.vue'


import { store } from '@/store.js'


describe('Login.vue', () => {
  let wrapper
  const localVue = createLocalVue()
  
  const vuetify = new Vuetify()
  localVue.use(Vuetify)

  const router = new VueRouter()
  localVue.use(VueRouter)
  let $route

  localVue.use(Vuex)
  let $store

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(Login, {
      localVue,
      vuetify,
      router,
      store,

      mocks: {
        $route,
        $store
      }
    });
  });


  it('login a account', async () => {
    const data = {
      email: "user@email.com",
      password: 'admin1234'
    }
    
    
    let email = wrapper.get('#text-field-email')
    let password = wrapper.get('#text-field-password')
    let button = wrapper.get('#button-login')

    email.setValue(data.email)
    password.setValue(data.password)

    await button.vm.$emit('click')
  });
});
```

this is the picture of error I received
[image]

Question: how can I introduce socket-io from vue test utils? What I am trying to achieve here is to mock